# evt.layers undefined while trying to display Legend widget in Javascript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, legend, feature-layer

I cannot get an ArcGIS Javascript API Legend widget to show up. An excerpt of my code is as follows. I believe I'm failing somewhere near the console.log that I call...undefined comes up in the console at this point. So for some reason evt.layers is not getting populated. Have I provided enough code? If you need more snippets I can copy/paste more.

```
        parser.parse();

        //initialize the map object
        map = new Map("map", {
            basemap:"gray",
            center: [-96.53, 38.374],
            zoom: 13
        });

        //access the hydro layer as a feature layer
        var hydro = new FeatureLayer("http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Hydrography/Watershed173811/MapServer/0", {
            mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
            outFields: ["*"]
        });

        //add hydro to map
        map.on("layer-add-result", function (evt) {
            console.log(evt.layers);
            var layerInfo = arrayUtils.map(evt.layers, function (layer, index) {
                return {layer:layer.layer, title:layer.layer.name};
            });
            if (layerInfo.length > 0) {
                var legendDijit = new Legend({
                    map: map,
                    layerInfos: layerInfo
                }, "legendDiv");
                legendDijit.startup();
            }
        });
        map.addLayers([hydro]);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on your answer, you could fix it one of two ways:

```
map.on("layers-add-result", function (evt) {
```

This works because `layers-add-result` only fires when calling the `map.addLayers()` function, which expects an array of map layers.

You could have kept `layer-add-result` which fires any time a single map layer is added. To add a single layer, use the singular function `map.addLayer(hydro)`

Comment: I'm confused because layer-add-result returns an error so you can see if the layer didn't load. But layers-add-result does not return an error. so if you add a set of layers you can't get errors?